# Save mapping of a particular key?

Tags: vim

How I can save mapping of a particular key in vim that I can map the key to another command and than restore the previous one? I also interested of saving mappings of a particular buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find out what e.g. `<Leader>x` is mapped to via

```
:map <Leader>x
```

If this is a plugin, it's likely something as `<Plug>PluginNameMappingName`.

You can then

```
:map <Leader>x :echo "something else"<CR>
```

and later restore via

```
:map <Leader>x <Plug>PluginNameMappingName
```

The same applies to buffer-local mappings; just use the `<buffer>` keyword in addition.

#### Alternatives

There's also `maparg()` to query this dynamically in Vimscript.

To temporarily override a global mapping, you can just define a buffer-local one; it'll override the global one, and then `:unmap <buffer> ...` when you're done. This only works in that buffer, of course, but you don't need to save and restore the original mapping.

#### Caveats

- This doesn't work well with `:map <expr>`, but those are rare, and should have been wrapped in a normal mapping, anyway.
- This also works with script-local mapping targets (that start with `<SNR>42_...`), but you don't hard-code that one, as the number depends on the sourcing order, and is bound to change.

Comment: How to save and restore it in vimscript, I mean the value of `:map <Leader>x`. And the value of `:nmap <Leader>x` is something like `n <Leader>x   <lots of spaces>   * <something>`.

Comment: May also want to look into [submode](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2467)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `maparg()` function to return a dictionary, containing the mapping and (almost) all flags.

For example you want to get the mapping of `<Leader>h` in normal mode, you can save the mapping using:

```
:echo maparg("<Leader>h", 'n', '', 1)
{'silent': 1, 'noremap': 0, 'lhs': '\h', 'mode': 'n', 'nowait': 0, 'expr': 0, 'sid': 37, 'rhs': '<Plug>(ChangesStageHunk)', 'buffer': 0}
```

To restore the mapping, you need to rebuild the command from that output, e.g. the above would be rebuild into:

```
:nmap <silent><nowait> <Leader>h <Plug>(ChangesStageHunk)
```

Hm, it looks like it is missing the `<script>` and `<unique>` flags.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `:h maparg()` to retrieve the right-hand side (and more) of a specific mapping:

```
:let foo = maparg('<F6>', 'n')
```